# How to add elements in list at odd indices?

Tags: python, list, indices

Say I call this function getSumOdds([1,2,3,4,5]). This should return 6 since 2 + 4 are located at odd indices. I have figured out how to get it to return what numbers are located at odd indices, but I am unsure how to add them.

```
    getSumOdds(aList):
        return aList[1::2]
```

All this does is return what numbers are at the odd locations. I also want it just to return aList. I have tried using sum() in various ways but nothing seems to work. Anything would help!!

Comment: Why not just sum that slice?

Comment: I'd also recommend a more pythonic method and call it `sum_odd_indices(a)` in keeping with the naming standards in python. if I were to call your method I might think it is going to sum the odd numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
getSumOdds(aList):
    return sum(aList[1::2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `sum(aList[1::2])` ?